# invoke Visual VM from java code using <http://visualvm.java.net/nonav/apidocs/13/>

Tags: profiling, visualvm, jvisualvm

Is there any way to invoke visualVM  through Java code and configure it to sample another Java program running on a remote host?or is there any other profiling tool which provides similar capabilities ?